Why does JAX compilation time grow with vmap batch size?
I'm using JAX to evaluate a batched loss gradient that involves some complicated linear algebra (including Cholesky decompositions and solutions, etc.). The schematic form of my gradient loss is
jax.jit( jax.value_and_grad( jax.vmap(loss)(...).mean() ) )

I'm finding that the compilation/first-evaluation time is constant up to a certain batch size given to the vmap (as I would expect in general), and then starts growing superlinearly. On an A100, it's something like 6 mins for nbatch <= 64, 13 mins for nbatch=128, 1 hour for nbatch=256, which becomes unwieldy.
Here is a reproducible example. After a lot of bisection, I think I see the same behavior for a simple batched cholesky:
# not much to see here, just setting up the linear system we'll be solving
nobs, ngp = 256, 64
t = np.linspace(0, 1, nobs)
f = np.arange(1, ngp + 1, dtype=np.float64)

fmat = np.zeros((nobs, 2*ngp), dtype=np.float64)
fmat[:,  ::2] = np.sin(2.0 * jnp.pi * f * t[:,np.newaxis])
fmat[:, 1::2] = np.cos(2.0 * jnp.pi * f * t[:,np.newaxis])

one, ones = jax.numpy.identity(nobs, dtype=np.float64), jax.numpy.ones(nobs, dtype=np.float64)

def func(pars):
  ftf = fmat @ jax.numpy.diag(pars**2) @ fmat.T + one
  cf = jax.scipy.linalg.cho_factor(ftf)
  b = jax.scipy.linalg.cho_solve(cf, ones)
  return b.mean()

then if I obtain the transform and compile it
jvg = jax.value_and_grad(lambda pars: jax.vmap(func)(pars).mean())
pars = jax.random.normal(jax.random.PRNGKey(0), (nbatch,2*ngp,))
jjvg = jax.jit(jvg).lower(pars).compile()

I find that the compilation time (in seconds) grows with nbatch:
[16,0.532], [32,0.507], [64,0.516], [128,0.580], [256,0.652], [512,0.822], [1024,1.7], [2048,2.75]

If I try jax.make_jaxpr instead of jax.jit, I see the same code for every batch size.
What could be going on here? I'm on JAX 0.4.26 and on a V100 with CUDA 12.2 and driver 535.104.05.

Is it possible to add a minimal reproducible example including an example of the loss function that exhibits these properties? Without knowing what code you're executing, it's hard to guess about the causes behind its performance.

It looks like another user is seeing the same issue: https://github.com/google/jax/issues/21313
